# Hypersurface vs Hyperplane

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, geometry

What is the difference between a hypersurface and a hyperplane (in the context of special relativity)? Is it right to think that a hyperplane is also a hypersurface but not vice versa?

Comment: hypersurfaces can be curved, hyperplanes are flat

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A hypersphere is a hypersurface that is not a hyperplane.  Hyperspheres and hyperplanes are examples of hypersurfaces.

It's akin to a sphere and a plane being hypersurfaces in three dimensions.